# Is it still possible to create mdi applications using the netbeans gui builder?

Tags: swing, netbeans, mdi, matisse, swingbuilder

I found an example @ http://matthewryan.info/netbeans/5.0/netbeans_mdi.html
But those options aren't present in the most recent version of netbeans. Is there another way to make internal frames using the builder or is it necessary to make the panels separately then add to a jinternalframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JInternalFrame is available in the Swing palette. They renamed it InternalFrame in the newest versions however. It can be found in the Swing Containers section.

Remember that you need to place the JInternalFrame inside a JDesktopPane and you should always place a JPanel inside the JInternalFrame as the top level component for the frame.